# Is there an Ubuntu 9.04 OpenJDK equivalent of sun-java6-plugin?

Tags: firefox, java

I'm wondering if there exists an implementation of a firefox plugin for OpenJDK, or how one would get firefox to use OpenJDK's java for applets. I've searched endlessly, and I can't seem to find any good resources.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for **icedtea6-plugin**.